# What's the meaning of multiple const qualifiers?

Tags: c, constants, declaration, function-signature

Code:

```
const char* const* const* foo(int bar);
```

I've seen double consts before which prevent the modification of the pointer too. First time i've seen triple const in my life. Wondering what its use is.

Comment: You can have a `const` for the base type plus one more `const` for each `*`; so `const char *const *const *const foo(int bar);` is valid.

Comment: Each `*` adds a level of indirection. And each level of indirection can also be cv-qualified.

Comment: It means each level of pointer indirection is const

Comment: why whould someone need constant pointer to constant pointer?

Comment: @LukášRutar: Same reason you might need `const` anything.

Comment: Use [cdecl translator](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+char*+const*+const*+foo).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your example all but the top level of indirection all `const` qualified.

```
const char            /* const qualified base level */
    *const            /* const qualified level 1 */
    *const            /* const qualified level 2 */
    *                 /* regular level 3 */
    foo(int bar);
```

`foo` is a function that accepts an `int` argument and returns a regular pointer.
The pointer it returns points to a `const` qualified pointer
which, in turn, points to another `const` qualified pointer
which points to `const` qualified `char`

Comment: Liked this answer the most :) Thanks !

Comment: I would like to see the face of your memory hierarchy when you dereference completely the data pointed by that kind of pointer... :)

Answer (score 14):

If you have a multilevel pointer, you have several pointer variables. Example:

```
char*** foo;
```

is accessed like this:

```
| foo | pointer1 | pointer2 | string |
   |    ^     |    ^     |    ^
    \___/      \___/      \___/
```

You can qualify each of the four locations in memory as being `const`, as in the declaration

```
const char *const *const *const foo;
```

However, best avoid becoming a three star programmer.

Comment: The main (sane) use I've seen for a `char ***` is when modelling an “out” parameter that tells the caller about an array of strings. Sprinkling all those `const`s in there just makes everything more confusing…

Comment: @DonalFellows being the ``three star programmer'' who wrote this, you're right in that it is meant to pass out an array of strings. You're wrong in that it only adds confusion, though.  It prevents user code from messing with that array or one of the strings it contains.

Comment: @fstd I know how to use a multi-`const` too. Still scares the horses.

Comment: @DonalFellows I wasn't explaining to you how it works, I was justifying the usage.  Don't see how it's anything scary -- in contrast, omitting the const would lead to a scary situation.  This is library code.

Answer (score 8):

Hah - the confusion around `const`.

Basically, if it qualifies a pointer, then it applies to the pointer immediately to its left. For example:

```
char *const c;
```

makes `c` a read-only pointer to `char`, whereas

```
const char *c;
```

Makes `c` a pointer to a read-only `char`, though you can change where `c` points to.

Of course, both the pointer and what it points to can be made read-only:

```
const char *const c;
```

This makes `c` a read-only pointer to a read-only `char`. With the former declaration, you can modify `*c`, but you can't modify `c` (i.e. you can't make it point to somewhere else). With the second, you can assign to `c` but not to `*c`, and with the third, you can't modify where it points to, nor can you modify the pointed-to object.

This extends to multiple levels of indirection. For your case, you might want to regroup the `const` keywords with the matching pointer that they are qualifying. This is mainly a whitespaces issue, but it would be like this:

```
const char *const *const *foo(int bar);
```

Which makes `foo` return a pointer to a read-only pointer to a read-only pointer to a read-only `char`. Read that carefully: note that given this piece of code:

```
const char *const *const *ptr = foo(0);
```

Then you know that assigning to `ptr` is legal, but any other assignment is illegal, namely, you can't assign to `*ptr`, `**ptr`, and `***ptr`.

Comment: I don't see how `ptr = "xpto"` is legal, when `"xpto"` is not a `const char* const* const`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops. Totally agreed. Removed that part, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There is nothing left of `const` in `const char *`.

Comment: @JanHudec the `const` there doesn't qualify a pointer, so the argument doesn't apply (it says only when `const` qualifies a pointer). But you can also write it as `char const *` if you want.

Answer (score 4):

`foo` returns a `pointer` which points to a `constant pointer` which points to another `constant pointer` which points to a `constant char`. Have a look at the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

```
int bar;
const char* const* const* ptr = foo(bar);
```

So basically you cannot change any of `*ptr` or `**ptr` or `***ptr`.